# What's the best way to apply mutiple jquery effects on one element consecutively?

Tags: jquery

I'm currenty trying to create a nice nested navigation menu. The problem I face is that I **want to make some elements change in a different way each time it is clicked**.

I don't really gasp how the DOM Tree respects my provious manipulations via Jquery...for example if i set a new class for a clicked element via the attr() function **I'm not able to select the newly changed element with its class atribute**.

Maybe I'm totally on the wrong track and this approch is wrong or must be tought in a different way. **I would be so happy to hear from more experienced people how they make consecutive manipulaions on elements.**

Here is what i try to achive: 1.) Trun it blue when clicked, 2.) turn it red when clicked again.

Here is a fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/YsQTL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                *//First time clicked--> this works*
                $("h1").click(function() {
                    $('h1').css({"color":"blue"}).attr('class','clicked').text('I should turn red if clicked again');
                });
                *//Second time clicked with added class "clicked"--> this doesn't work....why?*
                $(".clicked").click(function() {
                    $('h1').css({"color":"red"})
                    });
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id ="navigation">
            <h1>Title to be changed to blue if clicked</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is that you are binding the second event to elements that responds to the selector `.clicked` on page load, that is to say, none.

Instead, you could do something like this:

```
$("h1").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
        $(this).css({"color":"red"});
    }        
    else {
        $(this).css({"color":"blue"}).addClass('clicked').text('I should turn red if clicked again');
    }
});
```

This will bind the event to all elements responding to the selector `"h1"`, i.e. all your h1 tags present on the page at page-load, and inside the event handler, we check if the element has the class.

Also, keep in mind that since you were using the selector `$("h1")` instead of `$(this)` inside your event handler, every single h1 element on the page would get updated by your code, instead of just the one you actually clicked.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YsQTL/3/

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, using `.attr('class','clicked')` will remove all existing classes, and replace it with `clicked`. I'm not sure if that's what you intend to do, but it's recommended you use `addClass`, `removeClass`, and/or `toggleClass` for class manipulations.

Answer (score 1):

It's much code, and not pretty and not the best way to do so, but it would do what you want.

You could also achieve this with adding different Classes like

```
    $("h1").click(function(){
       var actColor = $(this).css("color");
        if($(this).hasClass("blueColor")){
               $(this).removeClass("blueColor");
               $(this).addClass("redColor");
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("redColor")){
               $(this).removeClass("redColor");
               $(this).addClass("blackColor");
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("blackColor")){
               $(this).removeClass("blackColor");
               $(this).addClass("blueColor");
        }
 });
```

**CSS Markup**

```
h1.blackColor{
    color:black;
}
h1.redColor{
    color:red;
}
h1.blueColor{
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Your first example probably won't work, since even though the `$(this).css("color", "red")` will result in `style="color: red;"`, reading it back with `$(this).css("color")` will give you an RGB code instead, i.e. `rgb(255,0,0)`. I don't know if this is jQuery's doing or browser-dependant behavior, but i wouldn't rely on the method.

Answer (score 1):

I might be new here but i think that this could be usefull:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

The toggle event.